# Lion (10.7) Not supporting Convert(1). Dylib error

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-lion

When trying to use convert(1), I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any idea how I could fix it ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was getting this error as well–with a homebrew install of ImageMagick. Along the same lines as Pascal, I fixed it with

1. Install XCode 4.1 (from the App Store)
2. In Xcode, go to Xcode > Preferences... > Downloads tab > click Install next to Command Line Tools
3. Uninstall ImageMagick with `brew uninstall imagemagick`
4. Update homebrew with `brew update`
5. Install latest homebrew with `brew install imagemagick`
6. Run `brew doctor` and delete any of the *.la and *.a files listed if step 4 fails on make install

Comment: Sorry, forgot I had this question on SO. This is exactly what I did. thank you.

Comment: Remember that installing XCode from AppStore doesn't really install it, it will leave you an "Install Xcode" icon installer in your App folder. Click on it.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and what solved the problem for me was:

1. Install the latest XCode version from the Mac Appstore
2. Install ImageMagick using [Macports](http://www.macports.org) (`sudo port install imagemagick`)

Both steps took a while, but in the end ImageMagick worked fine again.

Answer (score 5):

I installed xcode but had some issue with macports. Bummer!

I copied the libclparser.dylib file over from an old backup of 10.6, changed the permissions to match the other files in that folder and it worked!

Also see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674666/installing-imagemagick-leads-to-weird-error-involving-opencl

Edit:

I found this, which may be useful: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/
Also, the file is here: http://www.workdreamer.com/uploads/libclparser.dylib

Comment: I didn't want to copy a dylib file from an older version of OSX for obvious reason. I ended up reinstalling imagemagick with homebrew like @callmeed said

Comment: I bought a new laptop and I've got this problem again!

Comment: Oh, and again... How come I keep ending up here?

Comment: Great edit! http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ is awesome! :) Works perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling it even with brew instead of macports didn't work for me. Copying it did.

Comment: your library was most probably still linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
brew doctor
```

to diagnose the common problems.

One of it could be removing DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable from your ~/.profile

Or you have to re-install libtool by:

```
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```