# ImageMagick and OS X Lion trouble

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, osx-lion, dyld

**[edit]** I was troubleshooting problems with my development environment when I noticed one of my problems was the dependency on ImageMagick, since it's a vital part of my app.

---

After upgrading to OS X Lion (10.7) i no longer had ImageMagick available, i then tried installing again using MacPorts without success, i then installed from source, and the install wasn't very successfully i had convert and identify but it output error messages that i unfortunately dont have anymore, i by some strange reason decided to remove all of my MacPort libraries and started using Homebrew, i tried installing ImageMagick, it installs OK but when i try to use it throws this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libltdl.7.dylib provides version 10.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I read online but i have no clue on whats going on here, i found that libltdl is called libtool, and that i obviously need to upgrade it to a newer version, but i havent found any indication of how or where to find the source, or if this should be already be handled by homebrew and why it hasn't.

I tried installing ImageMagick again from source using [this installer script https://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl](https://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl) but when i try to use convert it throws a similar error.

```
$ convert gnome.jpg -resize 50% gnome_.jpg
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libltdl.7.dylib provides version 10.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5

$ which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

What can i do to solve my problem?

Comment: This is clearly not too general. This is about a missing library: /opt/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib. It should not have been closed.

Comment: If you upgraded XCode, be sure to reinstall the Command Line Tools as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6784216/102401. Also, I agree this should be reopened. I'm trying to tackle a specific programming issue where a script started reporting problems with ImageMagick and this is the first thing that came up when searching. None of the answers below worked, but I can't what did because the question is closed.

Comment: Agreed, I might be able to reword the question as a programming question see if it gets reopen

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<strike>I also upgraded to Lion and lost ImageMagick, although i'm getting different errors.</strike>

i found a [Lion distribution](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on imagemagick.org. not a big fan of the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable but it works.

ok scratch that. i just downloaded the ImageMagick source and re-compiled:

```sh
cd /tmp
curl -OL ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.7.2-7/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Howdy I tried this on a fresh Mountain lion install and it fails at the configuration stage `configure: error: libltdl is required for modules build`.  I am relatively new to compiling and installing binaries from source, can you provide a suggested best method to installing the required `libltdl` library?

Comment: I had originally used the [install script](https://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl) mentioned by @rroche on my snow leopard install. After the Lion upgrade i was able to use the code above because i had all the library dependencies installed already. The above code will NOT work on a fresh install.

Comment: the [script](https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer) mentioned by @23inhouse appears to [work on mountain lion](https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer/pull/35)

Comment: I ended up installing the command line tools from Xcode, which seems to install a relatively recent version of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 172):

On 10.8 I solved this issue with:

```
brew install libtool --universal
brew link libtool
```

If you don't know what brew is, visit https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew and its wiki.

Comment: Don't forget to install http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/ as well. And you're good to go

Comment: Worked for me without linking.

Comment: @user192411, because ImageMagick require libtool to be compiled.

Comment: Just `brew install libtool` appears to works just as well...  Why the `--universal` and manual `link` call afterwards?

Comment: This worked for me, though I had to do a `brew link libtool --force` since it was bitching about Keg-only installations. 

`brew doctor` also bitches about libtool. What's that about?

Comment: To reinstall: ```brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool```

Comment: see kenorb's answer: After mavericks upgrade you have to uninstall/reinstall libtool, even if the latest version is already installed.

Comment: I had to uninstall both imagemagick and libtool and reinstall libtool with the --universal flag then install imagemagick again.

Answer (score 66):

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

worked for me

Comment: this is not necessary just do a `brew install libtool` (since the precompiled imagemagick misses to download this dependency)

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks. even the brew install libtool was not working.

Comment: Saved my build of octave.  I also had to do `brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool`, `brew uninstall imagemagick`, brew install imagemagick --build-from-source`, then `brew link --overwrite imagemagick`

Comment: reinstalling libtool did not help me, but this worked.

Comment: Worked for me on Mavericks (10.9.3).

Comment: I had ```DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH``` exported from a previous manual installation which confused the brew installation. Close all terminals and retry.

Answer (score 30):

I too use homebrew for installing packages but imagemagick stopped working after upgrading OSX 10.8 to 10.9 (Mavericks). I had to do the following steps:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew uninstall libtool
brew install libtool --universal
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Why the `--build-from-source`? Well for me running `brew install imagemagick` on its own to install the pre-built binary wasn't sufficient; it fixed the original 'dyln' error but was replaced with:

```
unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1277
```

Comment: I was getting this error with PNGs despite having libpng installed.  Just doing the --build-from-source fixed it.  :)

Comment: I think all you need is to relink the packages. See this answer for a suggestion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123900/is-there-a-quick-way-to-relink-my-homebrew-kegs/123991#123991?newreg=f15c2f7e904f4de286b2d8b771b63d6f

Comment: holy, you just solved me so much headache! currently this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 18):

On Mountain Lion OSX,

Even with the updated brew for imagemagick(which includes libtool), this error seemed to happen to me.

so i fixed it using the following commands

```
brew uninstall libtool
brew install libtool --universal
brew link libtool --force
```

Comment: universal gives a single binary file which can be used for both 32bit and 64bit architectures. I think this is needed for Imagemagick to work.

Answer (score 8):

For others looking and still having trouble, I used this:

https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer

Comment: This doesnt play as nice with homebrew, as linkingvia `brew link` is done.  Manual links might/may/likely willl need to be done afterwards for complete access

Answer (score 7):

On 10.8, with brew, I solved this issue with:

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

For the googlers: If you happened to have it installed with brew beforehand, you'll need to reinstall by running  `brew uninstall graphicsmagick` before installing again. Easy.

Answer (score 7):

This helped me after restoring OS X 10.9.3 from time machine.

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew uninstall libtool
brew install libtool --universal
brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
brew install imagemagick
brew install Homebrew/python/pillow
brew link --overwrite pillow
```

Comment: and on El Capitan (10.11). I additionally needed to `chown -R myusername` a few folders (`/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/share`, `/usr/local/etc`), and replace the last line with `brew unlink pillow && brew link pillow`.
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

The same problem might occur with OSX Mountain Lion (preview 4). I had to configure some parts separately because there are some library incompatibilities:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0
```

I had to add `--with-fontconfig=no`, `--with-lzma=no` and use `/opt/local/share/...` instead of `/usr/local/share/...` for the ghostscript fonts:

```
cd /tmp
curl -OL ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.7.8-0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp --with-fontconfig=no --with-gs-font-dir=/opt/local/share/ghostscript/fonts --with-lzma=no
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 4):

I could fix the ImageMagick problem by installing corresponding package from [cactuslab site](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/).

Then by setting the `PATH` variables in terminal:

```
export MAGICK_HOME="/usr/local/ImageMagick/"
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), try the following command:

```
brew doctor
```

to diagnose the common problems.

One of it could be to remove DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable from your ~/.profile if you have it.

Or you have to re-install libtool by:

```
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

Comment: Thanks dude brew doctor was the answer, I actually have other libraries being link.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of the solutions above and they didn't work. Here's how I fixed my problem:

```
brew install imagemagick;
brew install freetype;
cd /usr/X11/lib/;    
sudo mv libfreetype.6.dylib libfreetype.6.dylib.orig;
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib libfreetype.6.dylib
```

Tested on OS X 10.7.2

Comment: maybe we should start comparing our brew installed libs

Comment: Here's the error message I was getting by the way: http://syskall.com/trouble-installing-imagemagick-on-os-x-1072 . Hope this fix works for someone else!

Answer (score 1):

For 10.7.8 and up, you have to install the php version and not the pecl version. Depending on your version of php you've install with Macports you can either do:

```
sudo port install php-imagick

sudo port install php5-imagick

sudo port install php53-imagick

sudo port install php54-imagick
```

Remember only to do the one of your current version of php.