# Rails paperclip `is not recognized by the 'identify' command`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, homebrew

I am getting an error when trying to save a `png` to a model with a paperclip attachment.

My `User` model:

```
class User < ActieRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :icon
  has_attached_file :icon, :url => "/system/users/icon/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_secret => "superSecretHashSecret",
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Example of trying to set an icon:

```
u = User.last
u.icon = open(Rails.root + "spec/fixtures/files/example.png")
u.save
```

Example model error:

```
:icon => ["/var/folders/43/810gn/T/example20121104-36855-1v7t136.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command."]
```

There are a number of people who have posted similar questions to this one, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996102/rails-paperclip-and-passenger-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command) but none of those solutions work for me.

My command_path is set correctly:

```
O:~ $ which identify
/usr/local/bin/identify
```

In `development.rb`

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

**This still might be the problem though.** 
When trying to use `identify directly I get the following error:

```
O:~ $ identify workspace/app/spec/fixtures/files/example.png 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

**Any suggestions as to what is going on here?**

I have tried reinstalling ImageMagick

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

Others have recommended adding `Rmagick`. It is definitely not a requirement for using Paperclip and it also did not help.

Another solution that has been suggested is removing the `:style` property. That isn't a solution though. I need to do the processing on the images.

I have Paperclip working on another model in my project that handles documents that are not images/don't do any processing. So I know that it is probably related to that.

Any other suggestions on how to address this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution ended up being to install `libtool`. This was the best suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412208/imagemagick-and-os-x-lion-trouble) as well. My issue proved more complicated because of `homebrew` not being up to date and in a state where it could not be updated without forcing a checkout of master.

For people that face this issue in the future, I recommend manually checking that the `identify` command actually works even if it is in your path.

```
identify /path/to/some/image
```

If it fails it will show something like:

```
O:~ $ identify workspace/app/spec/fixtures/files/example.png 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

In this case try installing `libtool`.

```
brew install libtool
```

If this fails, run `brew update`. If it continues to fail ensure that you have the latest Xcode installed and try updating again.

You will know this worked if you can successfully use `identity`. It will look something like this:

```
O:~ $ identify ~/workspace/app/spec/fixtures/files/example.png 
~/workspace/app/spec/fixtures/files/example.png PNG 200x201 200x201+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 66.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

The answer from glebm may very well have worked too. I have not taken a look at that installer.

Answer (score 9):

This is an ImageMagick installation problem.

First try

```
brew update
brew upgrade imagemagick
```

If that doesnt work, use *magick-installer* script to solve this:
https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer

```
curl https://raw.github.com/maddox/magick-installer/master/magick-installer.sh | sh
```

Alternatively, use a fork of *magick-installer* with newer versions of dependent libraries:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/GTSouza/magick-installer/master/magick-installer.sh | sh
```

Comment: Thanks glebm. I got it working by wrangling directly with homebrew for a while (seems likely this would have saved me the trouble though).

Answer (score 0):

This may caused by using old versions of Paperclip with newer and incompatible versions of the Cocaine gem. You can update paperclip gem version by using `bundle update paperclip`. It will update paperclip and cocaine versions as per compatibility.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1038

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue after upgrading to Mavericks on my Mac.

Here are the steps that fixed the problem:

```
brew update
brew install libtool
brew link libtool
brew upgrade imagemagick
```