# Imagemagick stopped working on OS X Mavericks

Tags: imagemagick, osx-mavericks

I had installed ImageMagick without any problems using the standard procedure (MacPorts) on Snow Leopard, however it has stopped working after an upgrade to Mavericks.
So, after much time spend looking at people with similar problems, I uninstalled it using port, then reinstalled using brew.
The installation worked fine as far as I can tell, however I now get an issue because of version incompatibility. This is what happens when I try to run convert:

```
ImageMagick reported error code 5. Message: dyld: Library not loaded:
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib Referenced from: 
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-0/bin/convert 
Reason: Incompatible library version: 
convert requires version 11.0.0 or later, 
but libltdl.7.dylib provides version 9.0.0
```

Apparently this library is out of date... but how to update it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412208/imagemagick-and-os-x-lion-trouble/11661050

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Maverick. My whole dev env was broken.

For fixing imagemagick - installed provided here - http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ 
helped me.

Hope it helps