# Is it safe to overwrite /usr/local/bin/convert on OS X?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, installation, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install imagemagick on OS X Mavericks. When I run `brew install imagemagick` I get this output at the end:

```
Warning: Could not link imagemagick. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link imagemagick'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/convert
/usr/local/share/man/man1/convert.1
==> Summary
```

I tried some of the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412208/imagemagick-and-os-x-lion-trouble) (not all though), but didn't get further. I also tried `brew link imagemagick`, but I get:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7... Warning: Could not link imagemagick. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/bin/convert
Target /usr/local/bin/convert already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

So my question: is it safe to run `brew link --overwrite imagemagick`? What could go wrong if I overwrite `/usr/local/bin/convert`?

Comment: Worst that could go wrong is that you'll end up with a broken ImageMagick which isn't much worse to where you stand right now. Check that /usr/local is not a symlink to anywhere else before doing any forced installations, though, just to make sure you're not actually writing stuff in /usr/bin.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How do I check that `/usr/local` is not a symlink to anywhere?

Comment: `ls -laid /usr/local`. If it is a sum link, it will show up with an 'l' in the left column and a `->` pointing at the target directory on the right

Comment: Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: any update or answer to this issue? I've run into the same problem. There is a binary in /usr/local/bin/convert prior to the imagemagick install. I think @AlexPopov question is the same as mine. What might have used this older version? Was it something bundled with OS X Mavericks?

Comment: @DogEatDog - I think this question got answered in the comments.

Comment: I removed the /usr/local/bin/convert using the brew link --overwrite. No issues so far --  I won't really know until I try something else and see if it breaks. :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after a bit of investigation, I'm pretty sure that the existing /usr/local/bin/convert was installed with MacTeX, which I did not install through homebrew. Replacing it with the homebrew installed 'convert' worked fine - you might want to back up the existing files beforehand just in case though.