# Paperclip in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am successfully running my Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 application in production mode on a [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) VPS. The only problem that I have is related to the Paperclip gem: it works in development mode on my local machine (this has Mac Os, Snow Leopard) but it doesn't work on the remote machine in production mode (this has Ubuntu 10.04 LTS).

I made some research on the net and I tried to solve that problem following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635840/probem-with-paperclip-accepting-jpg-and-png-on-production):

> On your production server, try running:
>
> which identify
>
> ...
>
> If it returns something like "/usr/bin/identify", then you'll want to
>   set the Paperclip options in your production.rb environment file to:
>
> Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"

Since I get the `/usr/bin/identify`, in my environment files I have the following scenario:

```
# `config/environments/development.rb`
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"

# `config/environments/production.rb`
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

Anyway in production mode Paperclip doesn't work. In development it works.

**How can I solve the problem?**

---

Following are some output:

```
>> $ <project_name> bundle show paperclip
=> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.3.16
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: paperclip should generate logs when calling identify / convert, do you see any?

Comment: @cam - The error that I am getting is 'Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.', but I installed ImageMagick! Probabily RoR doesn't "fill" it... how can I check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you determined if ImageMagick is installed with `which convert`? That requirement is discussed [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Note: the question was edited after this answer was posted. I cannot delete this answer as it has been accepted.

Comment: On the remote machine 'which convert' returns me '/usr/bin/convert', so I have to use "/usr/bin" for Paperclip. As I wrote in the question I already set that path on the remote machine. Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Why is my answer accepted and then downvoted if it doesn't solve your problem (not assuming you down voted)? Weirdness.. I'm tempted to delete it.